# excel function - lookup a value and transpose details in column in a row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a data in Sheet1 as below:

Akin 79

Akin 106

Akin 134

Akin 121

Arnett 477

Arnett 423

Arnett186

Arnett 129

Arnett 562

And I need to get data arranged in the following way, i.e. the values on the second column to be displayed in a single row against their respective unique name.

Akin    79  106 134 121

Arnett  477 423 186 129 562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the Pivot Table feature of Excel. Just follow the instructions given on this [Microsoft Office Excel Help page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx).